# What is the __DARWIN_C_LEVEL C-preprocessor symbol?

Tags: c, macos, posix, c-preprocessor

I recently received a patch that used `__DARWIN_C_LEVEL`. I think the person providing it uses OS X 10.10.

I have OS 10.9, 10.8 and 10.5 for testing, but none of them appear to define it.

***10.5***:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin PowerMac.home.pvt 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:57:01 PDT 2009;
root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_PPC Power Macintosh
$ cpp -dM < /dev/null | grep -i darwin
$
```

***10.8***:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin riemann.home.pvt 12.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.6.0: Wed Mar 18 16:23:48 PDT 2015;
root:xnu-2050.48.19~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ cpp -dM </dev/null | grep -i darwin
$
```

There are lots of hits for it, but its either a rip of Apple's source code or someone's patch. Confer, ["__DARWIN_C_LEVEL" site:opensource.apple.com](http://www.google.com/search?q="__DARWIN_C_LEVEL"+site%3Aopensource.apple.com).

Apple uses it like so, but its not clear to me what they are trying to achieve:

```c-preprocessor
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL > __DARWIN_C_ANSI
#define _POSIX_ARG_MAX      4096
#define _POSIX_CHILD_MAX    25
...
#endif
```

What is `__DARWIN_C_LEVEL`, and how should it be used?

Comment: Would this question not better be asked at the linked site?

Comment: maybe the difference between using ansi C, or C89 or C99 or C11?

Comment: Look at lines 582 of /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h

Comment: Edgar, perfect, thanks. It looks like it captures C characteristics modulo Posix. You should provide an answer.

Answer (score 8):

In `<sys/cdefs.h>` you will find:

```
/*
 * Set a single macro which will always be defined and can be used to determine
 * the appropriate namespace.  For POSIX, these values will correspond to
 * _POSIX_C_SOURCE value.  Currently there are two additional levels corresponding
 * to ANSI (_ANSI_SOURCE) and Darwin extensions (_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
 */
#define __DARWIN_C_ANSI         010000L
#define __DARWIN_C_FULL         900000L

#if   defined(_ANSI_SOURCE)
#define __DARWIN_C_LEVEL        __DARWIN_C_ANSI
#elif defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) && !defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE) && !defined(_NONSTD_SOURCE)
#define __DARWIN_C_LEVEL        _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#else
#define __DARWIN_C_LEVEL        __DARWIN_C_FULL
#endif
```

So `__DARWIN_C_LEVEL` will either be a valid _POSIX_C_SOURCE value (which look like dates like `199808L`) or it will be two values well outside that range `010000L` and `900000L` connoting, apparently, lots less posixy and lots more posixy.

- If `_ANSI_SOURCE` is defined `__DARWIN_C_LEVEL` will be `010000L`;
- else if `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is defined, but `_DARWIN_C_SOURCE` and
  `_NONSTD_SOURCE` aren't, `__DARWIN_C_LEVEL` will be whatever
  `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`s value is;
- else `__DARWIN_C_LEVEL` will be `900000L`.